# How to install octave with java on OS X using homebrew?

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, octave

I need to install octave with java 8 support, via homebrew, on OS X 10.12.2. I did `brew install octave --with-docs`, and it seemed to compile normally. I can start octave, but it lacks java support, which I need. From the octave console:

```
>> javaMethod('getProperty','java.lang.System','java.version')
error: javaMethod: support for Java was unavailable or disabled when Octave was built
>> octave_config_info ("features").JAVA
ans = 0
```

The only warning during the brew install was:

```
==> make install
Warning: homebrew/science/octave dependency gcc was built with a different C++ standard
library (libstdc++ from clang). This may cause problems at runtime.
```

I have previously installed: xcode and command line tools; `brew update && brew upgrade`; `brew install gcc`; `brew install Caskroom/cask/java` (and then command line `java -version` returns: "1.8.0_112"); and command line `/usr/libexec/java_home` returns: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home`

The only info that google finds is about how to compile withOUT java. The default is to compile with java, so I am suspecting that brew is not aware of the java 1.8 that is installed (despite it being installed by brew earlier today, and accessible by command line, and via `/usr/libexec/java_home`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the process changed recently and the wider documentation has not caught up (that I could find).

Solution: You now need to `brew install octave --with-java` to get java support.

Now in octave I get:

```
>> javaMethod('getProperty','java.lang.System','java.version')
ans = 1.8.0_112
```

Comment: What documentation have you used? As far as I can see the "--with-java" switch is there since 2015

Comment: Apparently I was not looking at the right documentation. I only saw this by looking in the recipe file. Maybe that is the proper doc, and I am just new to brew-ing

Comment: The "--with-java" switch is no longer supported and will raise an error if you use it. Instead, a simple "brew install octave" now includes the Java support. Seen with Octave version 6.4.0 in Homebrew.